# resample function of MATLAB signal processing toolbox does not work with "linear" method

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to use the resample function, and I've found the following in the document of MATLAB signal processing toolbox (https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html#d117e155565):

- y = resample(x,tx,___,method) specifies the interpolation method
  along with any of the arguments from previous syntaxes in this group.
  The interpolation method can be 'linear', 'pchip', or 'spline'.

The following is my code:

```
clear;

a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 0.5]; %original signal
tx = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
fs = 20; % resample frequency
[a_rs, ty] = resample(a, tx, fs, 'linear');

plot(tx, a, 'o', ty, a_rs, '.');
legend('original', 'resampled');
```

What I got is the following figure:

[resampled signal vs original signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIqWh.jpg)

Obviously it was not 'linearly' interpolated from the original signal. Instead, it seems a low pass filter was applied. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? Thanks a lot?

Comment: resampling is always done with filters, so you want interpolation with linear method, not resampling. try doc interp1 to see a nice example

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is somewhat difficult to read. You probably found:

> y = resample(x,tx,___,method) specifies the interpolation method along
>   with any of the arguments from previous syntaxes in this group. The
>   interpolation method can be 'linear', 'pchip', or 'spline'.
>
> Note:   If x is not slowly varying, consider using interp1 with the
>   'pchip' interpolation method. It interpolates x using linear
>   interpolation, not

So you have to look up where it actually uses interpolation. The  resampling itself will be done by `upfirdn`, not by interpolation. For your call syntax the relevant sentence is:

> The function interpolates x linearly onto a vector of uniformly spaced
>   instants with the same endpoints and number of samples as tx. NaNs are
>   treated as missing data and are ignored.

It interpolates prior to resampling with `upfirdn`. For this interpolation, you can change the method. I don't know the specific reason for the behaviour, but the function does what it is documented to do.